# FluentValidation: validation type names must be unique

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have the following rules specified in my code

```
    RuleFor(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring1Start).GreaterThan(DateTime.Now);

    RuleFor(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring1End).GreaterThan(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring1Start);

    RuleFor(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring2Start).GreaterThan(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring1End);
    RuleFor(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring2End).GreaterThan(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring2Start);

    RuleFor(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring3Start).GreaterThan(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring2End);
    RuleFor(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring3End).GreaterThan(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring3Start);

    RuleFor(x => x.Auction_Round2Start).GreaterThan(x => x.Auction_Round1Ring3End);
```

And I get this error

```
Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: required
```

I get this error on this line in a view

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Comment: Could you show your model class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you **haven't** decorated your view model class properties with any data annotation attributes.

Correct:

```
[Validator(typeof(MyViewModelValidator))]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring1Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring1End { get; set; }

    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring2Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring2End { get; set; }

    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring3Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring3End { get; set; }

    public DateTime Auction_Round2Start { get; set; }
}
```

Wrong:

```
[Validator(typeof(MyViewModelValidator))]
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring1Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring1End { get; set; }

    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring2Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring2End { get; set; }

    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring3Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Auction_Round1Ring3End { get; set; }

    public DateTime Auction_Round2Start { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my post with my model code.  As you can see I don't have the requried attribute anywhere.

Comment: What's the `AuctionMetadata` class? It seems to contain metadata about the Auction class. Also what about the `AuctionStatus`, `Invitation` and `Lot` classes? Do they contain data annotations? Are they decorated with a metadata class which might add data annotations?

Comment: Yep that was where the required attribute was - fixed - marked as answer :-)

Comment: Also I would recommend you to use view models instead of working with your domain models.

Comment: why is that.  The thing is that I am passing this very model object to my controller actions so as far as I know I must operate on them.

Comment: It is bad practice to pass your domain models to your views. They are not adapted to them. It is considered good practice to always design specific view models for each view and then map your domain models to those view models before passing them to the view.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Do you know any way to have Required annotation and the rules on the validator? Because the required generates a proper migration with nullable=false to prevent someone fiddling with records or making a mistake while managing the database